# Given array, create function and new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am given an array of data for a campsite, one of the key:value pairs being isReserved: false. I need to write a function called availableCampsites() and return an array with the campsites that are unreserved.

Here is the given campground array:

```
let campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }
];
```

What I have so far: (I've only been learning JS a few days, I know my code will be pretty bad)

```
function availableCampsites(campgrounds) {
  var openCampsites = [];
  var unreserved = campgrounds.isReserved;
    if (unreserved === false) {
      openCampsites.push(unreserved);
    }
  return openCampsites;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the filter method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you're new to JS, I think you should stick to the basics before moving to higher-order functions such as reduce, filter, etc. You've got the right idea, you're just missing the code which will loop through your array. In your function, `campgrounds` represents an array, which contains objects. You need to go through each object, and check if its `isReserved` property is false, and if it is, add it (push it), into your `openCampsites` array. In order to go through your array of objects, you can use a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), which will allow you to "grab" each object from your array, and check its `isReserved` property.

See code comments and example below for more details:

```js
function availableCampsites(campgrounds) {
  let openCampsites = [];
 
  // Loop through each index `i` in your array
  for(let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {
    let currentCampsite = campgrounds[i]; // get current camp ground at index `i` from your array
    
    // If current campsites isReserved property is false, then...
    if (currentCampsite.isReserved === false) { 
      openCampsites.push(currentCampsite); // add/push the currentCampsite object into your newly created array
    }
  }
 
  return openCampsites;
}

let campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }
];

console.log(availableCampsites(campgrounds));
```

Answer (score 2):

use JavaScript filter:

```
function availableCampsites(campgrounds) {
  return campgrounds.filter(campground => campground.isReserved == false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it using `Array.filter`.

```js
let campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }
];

const result = campgrounds.filter(({ isReserved }) => isReserved === false);
console.log(result);
```